# Where can you substitute in the initial value to solve for $C$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose you have an ODE like $e^x - \sqrt{y} \cdot y' = 0$ with the initial condition $y(0) = 1$. 
When using separation of variable, you have
$$
\int y^{1/2} dy = \int e^x dx
$$
and integrating, we have the following steps:
$$
\frac{2}{3}y^{3/2} = e^x + C \quad (1)
$$
and simplying, 
$$
y^{3/2} = \frac{3}{2} e^x + C \quad (2)
$$
and finally, 
$$
y = (\frac{3}{2} e^x + C)^{2/3} \quad (3)
$$

When solving for the value of $C$ using the initial conditions, why do I get different answers depending if I substitute into $(1)$, $(2)$, or $(3)$.

For example, plugging into $(1)$, I have $\frac{2}{3} = 1 + C$ and so $C = - \frac{1}{3}$. But into $(3)$, I have $1 = (\frac{3}{2} + C)^{2/3}$ and so $C = \frac{-1}{2}$.

What is causing this? I was under the impression this should not happen.

Comment: $C$ means something different in line (1) and line (2)....

Comment: @T.Bongers I understand that in line (2), that $C$ is really $2/3 C$. But I thought it was kosher to "handwave" the "absorption" of the constants?

Comment: When you actually solved for $C$ from line (1), you're assigning a numerical value to $C$. It's no longer something arbitrary, and changing it matters.

Comment: @T.Bongers Why in line (1) is this a problem, but in line (2) and (3) you achieve the right constant?

Comment: If you rearrange $2/3 y^{3/2} = e^x - 1/3$, you get $y^{3/2} = \frac 3 2 e^x - \frac 1 2$, exactly as in lines (2) and (3).

Comment: **HINT**: $C\text{(from line 1)}\times\frac{3}{2}=C\text{(from lines 2 or 3)}$. If you had changed $C$ to, say, $D$ in lines 2 and 3 then it would have made things a lot more obvious.

Comment: @T.Bongers OH. Wow.  I see now. Thanks for helping me. I appreciate you.